# Onclick на AJAX элементах

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Знаю, что тема обсуждалась много раз, но вопрос все равно без ответа.

Есть кнопка, которая загружается через AJAX

```
<div onclick='action()'>Кнопка</div>
```

И есть скрипт в теле документа

```
<script>
  function action(){
    alert("OK!");
  }
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что кнопка не видит скрипт. Знаю что можно повесить событие в самом скрипте, но можно ли сделать именно через `onclick`?

Comment: Попробуй обработчик так навешивать,ajax  данные чуть по другому обрабатывать надо $("body").on("click", "div", function() { alert("ok") })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понятно, в чём проблема. Вот рабочий пример:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = 
    '<button type=button onclick=action()>Button</button>';
}, 1500); // Имитация ajax

function action() {
  console.log('OK');
}
```

```html
<output>Загрузка...</output>
```

Comment: Действительно( В коде ошибка была, но все равно спасибо